# Order by on ToMany collections with fetch="EAGER" doesn't work

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

When using `order-by` on ToMany collections with fetch="EAGER", order by isn't taken into account.

It works when you remove the EAGER fetch.

```
<one-to-many target-entity="TopTenItem" mapped-by="list" field="items" fetch="EAGER">
  <order-by>
    <order-by-field name="position" direction="DESC"/>
  </order-by>
</one-to-many>
```

Is this a known bug or by design?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a know bug https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/4256 that still is not fixed.

Comment: @Yunnosch why? look at what the question is asking. this looks fine to me. it would be nice to elaborate if there's more info in the linked resource though

Comment: @starball I see what you mean. To "... details ... Is this a known bug or by design?" the answer "Yes, it's a know(n) bug.(see link)" is indeed an answer. Good point. Sorry, I did not read thoroughly enough to the end....